# iOS : How To Make Static or Fix Background on View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 2 ViewControllers, both have this code in their .m file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]]];

}
```

and I have push transition between both ViewControllers. So when it run on my iPod, it looks like the second background push first background from right to left.

but that's not what I want because the background for both ViewControllers are same. I only need to move the UI components (buttons, text field, label, etc) on ViewControllers 1, not the background when transition runs.

also when UI components from ViewControllers 2 slide in. only the components slide in.

how to perform this? thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first view controller loads, add the background as a subview of the *window* inserted *behind* the view of the view controller. Then make the view controllers view transparent. Two things to consider with this: make sure you hold a reference to it so you can remove the background when the view controller is dismissed. Second, this background will not auto-rotate with the view controllers view on top of it.

Now, thats a direct answer to your question. If you can get what you want by doing what incmiko suggests, you'll be the best off.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:<#(UIColor *)#>]
```

and on your viewcontrollers clear the background:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor ClearColor]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use 2 ViewControllers. Use one, and add your UI componets into two views. Then move them with animations.

Add two views to your ViewController. Add your "First ViewController" UI components to either of them, then add your "Second ViewController" UI components to the other. Move them with animations, like your seque. You could use this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.
 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

      firstView.center = CGPointMake(Pointx, Pointy);
      secondView.center = CGPointMake(Pointx2, Pointy2);

      } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi Incmiko, I want to clear myself with your suggestion. You mean, on my Storyboard, I only have 1 ViewController, but I must add multiple 'View' components (UIView) so I can perform what I want? Is that what you mean?